# Confusion with mount points in Linux

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, mount

I am a former Windows user who has migrated to Linux (read Ubuntu) full time. Though in my PC I have kept the Windows partitions intact, I have bought a new Laptop whose hard disk I want to partition. Had it been Windows, I would have partitioned its 1 TB partition as follows:

```
Music - 250 GB
Videos - 550 GB
Important - 100 GB
Swap - 8 GB
OS - 23 GB
```

Now in Linux, I know the mount points for some,

```
OS - /
Home - /home
```

But I can't understand what mount points to set for Music, Videos and the Important partition containing family photos and documents. I'll be grateful, if anyone could shed some light on it.

Thanks
EG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can leave your partitions as it was and just create a symbolic link to those music partition or any other ones in your home directory.
2. During installation you can mount `musics partition` as `/home/USERNAME/Musics`
3. After simple installation you can change your `/etc/fstab` and point `/home/USERNAME/Musics` to your musics partition. you can find a good information of how to do so from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab. And also there is a full manual available by typing `man fstab` in terminal.

Comment: What do you mean by leave. I am not creating any partitions in windows. Can I create my own custom mount points?

Comment: Yes you can create your own custom mount points. Even before installation or after. By "leave" I mean just install your Ubuntu in `One` partition as you like, then adjust your mounting points.

Comment: But then I I ever want to reinstall, then I'll lose all my data. If I have a separate partition mounted at / then I'll just have to format that partition before a new installation, right?

Comment: You won't loose any data. Edited my answer, check that.